# Sliding Menu with tabs

Tags: android

I am pretty new in Android. I want to know if it is possible to use a slinding menu(like facebookApp) with a fragment canteining Tabs. I mean, once I choose an option from de menu, then I can see Tabs. I've been searching around, but i can't find something useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this out: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just implement the Sliding Menu Library, and when you click a Menu Item from the Sliding Menu, start an FragmentSlidingActivity(Fragment Activity extends SlidingMenu's FragmentActivity to be able to slide) which has Tabs with Fragments inside.

And if you are looking for different back stack for each tab under Tab Host (like it is used to be with TabActivity which is deprecated ), you can take a look on my example project on [GitHub](https://github.com/osayilgan/samples).

[Here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) is the link to the Sliding Menu Library.

Comment: How should I call the FragmentActivity from the sliding menu(SherlockFragmentActivity)

Comment: It has a List View where the All Side Menu Items contained. Implement an onItemClickListener and start an Activity when onClick.